# QGIS does not read ESRI Geodatabase correctly

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I have a geodatabase from the EPA that does not seem to me reading correctly with Quantum GIS. QGIS Version 1.8.0 (Lisboa) and GDAL/OGR 1.9.2

When I open the attribute table the first two columns have the same data. The first column is CERCLA_ID and the second is SITE_NAME. Both columns have the SITE_NAME value. As far as I can tell all else is correct.

I opened various files in the .gdb folder using a hex editor and in the a00000004.gdbtable file the data is stored in an XML format internally and the correct CERCLA_ID value is indeed being stored along with the SITE_NAME.

Is there something wrong with the file or something wrong with the program?

I also heard back from my EPA contact. He says they are using "attribute domains" on their end.

Answer (score 3):

Opening GDBs is not a problem anymore. Use Add Vector layer | Directory | OpenFileGDB:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to a computer with ArcGIS you might want to try a simple workaround, export from ArcCatalog the shapefiles in the Geodatabase, and try if they work as independent *.shp into QGIS.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.  As they haven't mentioned they have access to ArcGIS, you should probably assume that they don't have it.

Comment: I thought that too, but they had no answer for 3 years. If no one has figured it out in that time, maybe that is what they finally did. I don't know...

Comment: It's a bad workaround since it is no problem anymore to load .gdb in QGIS.