# Attribute error with FileGDB

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I have a large ESRI file geodatabase, that I loaded into QGIS with no problems. If I look at the attributes tab in the properties dialog, the fields are as they should be.

One of the fields is supposed to have small integers. If I try to symbol by this attribute, it gives me four levels: `10005`, `48255`, and `152528`, but almost all of the features are missing the attribute. I cannot open the attribute table without QGIS crashing. Here's a screenshot of the file with the supposed symbology.
[image: gdb_qgis]

If I save the `.gdb` as a shapefile, then the attributes are properly coded and assigned. Here's the shapefile symbology.
[image: shp_qgis]

It seems as though there is a problem with how QGIS is handling the attributes table, but that `filedb` is all right because the shapefile export is fine. I would file a bug report, but I'm wondering if the community has a known workaround or things I could check.

#### session info

OS X 10.10 Yosemite
QGIS 2.8.0
GDAL/OGR1.11.2

Comment: *similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69211/qgis-does-not-read-esri-geodatabase-correctly but that is outdated and has no adequate answers*